# Lock in amplifier reference signal

Tags: amplifier, oscillator

I have assigned an engineer to use lock-in detection to measure a signal that is being modulated at a specific frequency near 8 khZ.  The signal is modulated internally by the device he is measuring, and because he could not find a way to output that signal to the lock-in reference input he used the lock-in's internal reference, which he set at the same frequency as the signal he is trying to measure.  I told him that this would not work, since two separate oscillators could never maintain the same phase relationship even if they are at the same frequency.  However, he showed me that he actually could produce a DC output from the lock-in (R channel), and that it disappeared if he varied the lock-in internal reference frequency slightly.  After a while I realized that he was using a time constant that is very short relative to the time that the phase relationship of the two oscillators was changing, and showed him that if he increased the time constant to >1 second his DC output dropped.  My question however, is whether using the internal oscillator at the same frequency as the external signal, combined with a short time constant, is a valid method we can use on this system.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really trust it.

As you have pointed out, the whole point of lock-in amplification is that you know that the frequency and phase of the signal used to modulate the physical system. Two oscillators which are not phase-locked to some sort of master reference *will* drift apart from each other. If you plot the measured signal over time you will see it vary sinusoidally with a frequency equal to the difference in frequency between the two oscillators. It doesn't matter how close you get them to the same frequency, they are certain to drift eventually. This is why as you increase your time constant (ie: tighten the passband of the lowpass filter) the signal starts to vanish.

So, about all you can do is basically just use the lock-in amp as a bandpass filter/envelope detector. You'll need a dual-phase lock-in amp for this. If you have a dual-phase lock-in amplifier, you will have an in-phase and quadrature component output. Mathematically, you can consider their output to be a complex number encoding the magnitude and phase of the measured signal.

Since your oscillators aren't locked, you pretty much have to throw out the phase and just look at the magnitude. That'll just be the vector magnitude of the in-phase and quadrature signals:

$$ \left | s(t) \right | = \sqrt{I(t)^{2}+Q(t)^{2}} $$

Some fancier lock-in amps have a button for this, which gives the vector magnitude as an output.

This may or may not work for your application. You will lose a lot of the noise immunity advantages you get from synchronous lock-in amplification.

Personally, I would have your engineer crack open the device under test and probe until he finds the clock signal, then solder on a wire, but that's just me :).

Comment: Thank you Peter.  We have definitely tried to output the clock signal from the device, but no luck so far.  Our lock-in is a dual phase SRS830 and we are looking at the vector magnitude (R) output, which he demonstrated for a 100 mS constant is exactly the RMS we should expect if we were doing lock-in detection.  I understand we will not get any phase information, which is unfortunate because that is one of the outputs we are looking for, but seems like over this time constant the phase difference between the two oscillators is constant enough that we are effectively getting lock-in detection.

Comment: Gotcha. Since you're looking at the vector magnitude output, the fact that you're seeing a drop at longer time constants makes sense (since the slight frequency difference between the two oscillators creates a beat frequency which will be filtered out at the longer time constant). This setup should work for you in the short term but I would caution against trusting it in the long term, as oscillators can age differently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful input Peter, and we will continue our search to get the clock signal out and do 'real' lock-in detection.  We have a couple options still to try.